# Python return integers for letters in a string?

Tags: python, string, ascii

I'm trying to convert a string of letters to integers, say 'ABC' to '123'.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: is there a pattern defined or you just want random digits?

Comment: I was trying to match up letters to their order in the alphabet.  Ord() is what I was looking for.  I should of remembered that, a trivial post, and downvoted as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to create a direct translation table (like for a Caesarian cypher), the previous suggestion of string.maketrans is a good one.

But your question is a bit vague, and another possibility is that you need to look up numbers that relate to your character for some deeper purpose (like ASCII or unicode encoding). In that case, the [chr()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#chr%22chr%28%29%22) and [ord()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#ord%22ord%28%29%22) functions may be useful.

Comment: Hello abought, yes this is something I knew.  It slipped my mind but, it was good that I learned something from gnibblers comment.  This wasn't question worthy.

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> import string
>>> trans = string.maketrans("ABC","123")
>>> "ABC".translate(trans)
'123'
```

Comment: Hey thanks gnibbler, I've never seen strings maketrans before.  I'll give it a look.